# VScode setting change. Is there a way?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Whenever I make changes to my code in VScode, I have to save it before I can run the updated version. Is there a shortened way to do this?

Comment: you have to save a file in order to be able to compile it.  Ctrl-S will do that.

Comment: There is [autosave](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save). But it's not clear whether that will meet your needs exactly as it will save not on run but periodically and on certain windowing events.